# Native libraries not running on the device

Tags: maven, libgdx

I've put armeabi,armeabi-v7a folders into libs folder and not in maven repository. But I am getting following error while using libgdx:

The library 'gdx-backend-jogl-natives.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
The following libraries were found:

- libgluegen-rt-linux32.so
  -libgluegen-rt.jnilib
- libgluegen-rt-linux64.so
- libjogl.jnilib
- libjogl_awt.jnilib
- libjogl_awt-linux32.so
- libjogl_awt-linux64.so
- libjogl-linux32.so
- libjogl-linux64.so
- liblwjgl.jnilib
- liblwjgl.so
- liblwjgl64.so
- libopenal.so
- libopenal64.so

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdx-backend-jogl-natives.jar file contains the basic information about how to create the window in desktop environment. So when you provide android environment it will conflict with android native library so it throws an error. so you have to remove the native library from the project then check it will execute successfully.

Comment: I have somewhat similar error, but I actually know that I need that library (so I don't want to remove i), and I also know that my phone *does* support the features (cardboard VR). I'm scratching my head.

Comment: By removing the native library - do you mean removing the armabi-v7 and armsbi folders?