# How to solve library issue(s) in Selenium?

Tags: java, android, selenium

I try to use Selenium in my application so I have added the library **selenium-java-2.30.0.jar** to the build path and the following imports to the activity class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;
```

However; whenever I try to run the application in the emulator (avd 2.2 and 4.2) I keep receiving the following errors:

```
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx] The library 'selenium-java-2.30.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx] The following libraries were found:
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/amd64/libibushandler.so
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/amd64/x_ignore_nofocus.so
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/x86/libibushandler.so
[2013-02-21 19:03:46 - xxxx]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/x86/x_ignore_nofocus.so
```

and launch is canceled. I have already cleaned the project but still got the same messages. Is this an emulator problem or I'm using wrong libraries?

Comment: It sounds like either an emulator problem or you're including the wrong selenium libraries. Have you seen the [note about supported platforms](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Supported_Platforms)?

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189675/native-libraries-not-running-on-the-device. It seems that removing of native libraries can help.

Comment: @dummersl This is actually the tutorial I'm following. The same problem in the two different emulators?

Comment: @llia How can I then remove conflicting libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. Instead of using **selenium-java-2.30.0.jar** available in the downloads section at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list I went to the Android SDK Manager and installed appropriate libraries from there.

In Eclipse go to Window -> Android SDK Manager -> select: Available packages → Extras → Google → WebDriver

After installing the GoogleWebDriver go to *android/sdk/extras/google/webdriver/* directory, find and copy **android_webdriver_library.jar** library and paste it into lib folder of your project. Afterwards you can import earlier mentioned statements and use the Selenium web driver classes.