# AndroidDriver - Selenium library issues and unable to read AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run the example test found here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Run_the_Tests on an Android emulator (Mac), but I'm running into problems when trying to run the test.

I have set up an emulator and installed the WebDriver APK, then in Eclipse I created a new Android Application Project and created a class OneTest.java and copied in the code (also imported org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; which was missing from the example code). Then I imported the two selenium-java-2.33.0 jars into the library. I also updated my androidmanifest to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.test" />
</manifest>
```

When I try to run OneTest.java as an Android Junit Test I see the error:

```
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test] The library 'selenium-java-2.33.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test] The following libraries were found:
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/amd64/libibushandler.so
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/amd64/x_ignore_nofocus.so
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/x86/libibushandler.so
[2013-07-25 11:53:36 - Test]  - org/openqa/selenium/firefox/x86/x_ignore_nofocus.so
```

If I ignore the error and try to run it again I see:

```
[2013-07-25 11:59:43 - Test] Installing Test.apk...
[2013-07-25 11:59:44 - Test] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-07-25 11:59:44 - Test] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-07-25 11:59:44 - Test] Launch canceled!
```

And in LogCat:

```
07-25 10:59:44.188: D/zipro(23141): Zip: EOCD not found, /data/local/tmp/Test.apk is not zip
07-25 10:59:44.188: D/asset(23141): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/Test.apk'
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/Test.apk
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:733)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:171)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/PackageParser(23141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-25 10:59:44.219: W/DefContainer(23141): Failed to parse package
```

I did try the suggestion here [How to solve library issue(s) in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015264/how-to-solve-library-issues-in-selenium) to use android_webdriver_library.jar instead, but I got errors on import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver; and WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(); I can resolve the first one by using android.AndroidWebDriver; but I can't resolve the issue with AndroidDriver().

Any help would be great since I'm an Eclipse/Android noob :)

Edit: I progressed a bit by adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to the manifest, but I see the error "Could not find class 'org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver', referenced from method com.example.test.OneTest.testGoogle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved most of my problems by creating a Java Project, including a main method and running this as a Java Application. I also had to import selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar otherwise I'd run into an error when running the test.